# HCI Active Bluetooth LE Scan / Scanresponse for specific UUID?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

I am looking for a way to do a active Bluetooth LE Scan for a specific MAC / UUID only. In other words: I want the scanresponse of a specific device only. All other (passively) scanned devices should **not** be asked for scanresponse (to save power).

I saw that HCI has a Whitelist and a Resolvinglist:

- Would a whitelist limit scanresponse to the whitelisted devices?
- What is the resolvinglist for?

If none of those options work:
If I start a passive scan, is there a way to request scanresponse for a specific device via HCI?

Answer (score 2):

<del>I'm not sure BLE works that way...  Regular bluetooth sends additional requests to get details about a device, but I don't think BLE does that.  There's only one type scan and I think that's passive.</del>

As for the whitelist, that's for something else.  What you can do with the whitelist is put a list of devices in there that you want to automatically connect to.  You can then issue a command to initiate connections with all devices found that are in the whitelist.  This saves you manually watching for ad packets and issuing separate commands for each device you want to connect to.  The whitelist won't affect what you see when scanning.

I'm not sure what the "Resolving List" does, that may do what you want...

**EDIT:**

Okay, I did some Google searches and it seems like there's an "active" scan for BLE, but I've never used it.  If there's a passive/active difference then there must also be a way to query a single device for additional information after doing a passive scan.